# PHP - Remove zeros before number in URL

Tags: php, regex, url, preg-replace, zero

I am programming an api that captures the thumbnail of a remote XML.
But for some reason the XML gives me a url that ends in a number plus the .jpg extension. But this url is unsuccessful, I did the test by removing the zeros before the numbers and the URL works, so will there be a way to remove those zeros from the URL with PHP?

Fail URL:

```
https://cdn.example.com/z=e0fg4/video/2234554/04/101123142/original/015.jpg﻿
```

Good URL:

```
https://cdn.example.com/z=e0fg4/video/2234554/04/101123142/original/15.jpg﻿
```

Comment: Is `015.jpg` a separate value, or is it always a full URL? If it's always a full URL, is `/original/` always a part of it?

Comment: / original / will always be part of this and /015.jpg may vary, for example /006.jpg

Comment: `\/(0*)\w+\.` this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't done PHP in years, but something like this might do the trick

```
preg_replace("/(.*)(0)([\d]*\.jpg)$/", "$1$3", $input_lines);
```

http://www.phpliveregex.com/p/ltJ

For more than one trailing zero use this:

```
preg_replace("/(.*\/original\/)(0*)([\d]*\.jpg)$/", "$1$3", $input_lines);
```

http://www.phpliveregex.com/p/ltL

Comment: And how would you do if there is more than 1 zero.
It seems to work but only extracted 1 single zero.

Comment: Im getting it: Warning: preg_replace(): Unknown modifier ')'
$data = preg_replace("/(.*\/original/)(0*)([\d]*\.jpg)$/", "$1$3", $data);

Comment: You probably only want to do a replacement if there is actually a leading `0` otherwise you're just wasting time. Therefore I recommend replacing the `0*`, which looks for zero or more `0`, with `0+` which will require at least one `0`.

Comment: Okay, I just did some tests and now this works fine. Just note that I missed a "/" because otherwise I got an error in PHP.
preg_replace("/(.*\/original\/)(0+)([\d]*\.jpg)$/", "$1$3", $input_lines);

Answer (score 0):

Just in case someone needs it, I have modified Baruch's answer, since it is only limited to the url preceding the word **/original/**, to accept any word I made the following modification:

```
preg_replace("/(\/.*\/)(0*)([\d]*\.jpg)$/", "$1$3", $input_lines);
```